# Trying to create backup of SQL Table

Tags: sql, oracle

While creating a backup of a table, I am using the following Syntax -

```
CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE original_table;
INSERT new_table SELECT * FROM original_table;
```

But while executing the first Statement only, I am getting the folowing error:

> SQL-Fehler: ORA-00922: Fehlende oder ungültige Option
>   00922. 00000 -  "missing or invalid option"

I am new to SQL but this should be simple execution.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: I am using Oracle.

Comment: That's an Oracle error I don't  know that mysql has this option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In oracle you should use  CREATE AS select

```
CREATE TABLE new_table 
AS SELECT * FROM original_table
```

in mysql  CREATE SELECT

```
CREATE TABLE new_table 
SELECT * FROM original_table
```